# Flask-OAuthlib OAuth2 client Error: "Missing access credentials."

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, foursquare, flask-oauthlib

I'm using Flask OauthLib following this tutorial, trying to make a basic OAuth2 client to use with Foursquare.com: https://flask-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/client.html#oauth2-client

After I grant permission to use the app, I get redirected to a page with this text:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "code": 400, 
    "errorDetail": "Missing access credentials. See https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/oauth.html for details.", 
    "errorType": "invalid_auth"
  }, 
  "response": {}
}
```

What is wrong? How do I fix this? Thanks.

**Foursquare app settings:**

Redirect URI(s):
`https://127.0.0.1:5000/login/authorized`

**github.py** (A slightly modified version of https://github.com/lepture/flask-oauthlib/blob/master/example/github.py )

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, session, request, jsonify
from flask_oauthlib.client import OAuth


app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.secret_key = 'development'

oauth = OAuth()
foursquare = oauth.remote_app(
    'foursquare',
    app_key='FOURSQUARE',
    consumer_key='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    consumer_secret='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
)

app.config['FOURSQUARE'] = dict(
    consumer_key='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    consumer_secret='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    base_url='https://api.foursquare.com/',
    request_token_url=None,
    access_token_url='https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token',
    authorize_url='https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate',
)
oauth.init_app(app)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    if 'foursquare_token' in session:
        me = foursquare.get('v2/users/self')
        return jsonify(me.data)
    return redirect(url_for('login'))


@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return foursquare.authorize(callback=url_for('authorized', _external=True))


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('foursquare_token', None)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


@app.route('/login/authorized')
def authorized():
    resp = foursquare.authorized_response()
    if resp is None:
        return 'Access denied: reason=%s error=%s' % (
            request.args['error'],
            request.args['error_description']
        )
    session['foursquare_token'] = (resp['access_token'], '')
    me = foursquare.get('v2/users/self')
    return jsonify(me.data)


@foursquare.tokengetter
def get_foursquare_oauth_token():
    return session.get('foursquare_token')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('127.0.0.1', debug=True, port=5000, ssl_context=('/Users/XXXXX/Development/Certificates/server.crt', '/Users/XXXXX/Development/Certificates/server.key'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a scope too: for example:

```
request_token_params={
    'scope': [
         'https://mail.google.com/',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit.readonly',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read',
]
```

Comment: Still not working for me. Could not access resource: 400 {"meta":{"code":400,"errorType":"invalid_auth","errorDetail":"Missing access credentials. See https:\/\/developer.foursquare.com\/docs\/oauth.html for details.","requestId":"59f22a454c1f670ffc0a61c0"},"response":{}}

Comment: Which oauth2 are you using?

Comment: Apache Oltu API.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46961234/apache-oltu-foursquare-integration-not-working